# how to use 年をめどに

Tags: time

i just learned this grammar from Nikkei News:
 `

> 2021年度をメドに

mean an action target time is within 2021. Some site use:

> 2021年をめどに

so what is different of them? 
if i want say: target in 09/2021, how i can say?

and i want to say: i will complete that within 2 year, how i can say?

Comment: As for 年度, visit the following site. http://english.cheerup.jp/article/2889

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is an important difference between 「2021年{ねん}」 and 「2021年度{ねんど}」.

「2021年」 refers to the ***calendar*** year, January 2021 through December 2021.

「2021年度」 refers to the ***fiscal/business*** year, April 2021 through March **2022** (for most organizations).

In other words, those two terms refer to two different 12-month periods.  You will need to be aware of the difference for as long as you study Japanese.

Moving on to 「めど」.

**「めど」 roughly means "aim", "goal", "outlook", etc.** in planning and executing activities.  "**Target deadline**" may be the better term this time.

> if i want say: target in 09/2021, how i can say?

You could say:

> 「2021年9月 + **を** + めど + **に** + Verb Phrase」

The two particles, を and に, are important and are not replacable by others.

> and i want to say: i will complete that within 2 year, how i can say?

You could say:

> 「2年{ねん}をめどに（完了{かんりょう}する/仕上{しあ}げる）予定{よてい}です。」